# Angular ui-router bound state to URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm struggling with this counfiguration of `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` for days now.

My problem is, in fact, that after I use `$state.go()`, state changes normally, but url in browser stays the same (`#/`).

Additionaly, when I set the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');` option, after every `$state.go()` router redirects to `/home`, no matter what state was picked.

---

My configuration:

```
StateConfiguration.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function StateConfiguration($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

    addState("state1", "/state1", "<example-page></example-page>");
    addState("state2", "/state2", "<example-page2></example-page2>");
    addState("register", "/register", "<register-page></register-page>");
    addState("error", "/error", "<error-page></error-page>", {
        error: null
    });
    addState("myLibrary", "/my-library/{groupId}{groupName}", "<my-library></my-library>", {
        groupId: null,
        groupName: null
    });
    addState("home", "/home", "<main-page></main-page>");
    ///////////////////////////

    function addState(stateName, url, template, params){
        $stateProvider.state(
            stateName, 
            {
                url: url, 
                template: template,
                params: params || {}
            }
        );
    }
}
```

---

Can somebody point me, where I have error? Every state just uses another directive.

My goal is that when application changes state, the url in browser changes as well. Additionally, when user enter url like `app.com/state-url`, application redirects to state with url `state-url`. How should I do it?

---

### UPDATE

As requested, I'm adding `$state.go()` calls, but they're not very "big".

```
service.home = function(params){
    $state.go("home", params);
};

service.register = function(params){
    $state.go("register", params);
};
```

Also, after looking closer, after going to `register` state, url changes for 0.5 s to `register` and then, goes back to `home`.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of this is wrong:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

The clue is in the name (urlRouterProvider) - it deals with url, not state, so you should do it like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

I can't comment on your $state.go calls, because you haven't provided examples of those.

Comment: No luck - after i changed it to `/home`, still the same behaviour. I will update post in a minute and add informations about `$state.go()`.

Comment: A couple of things, if your state.go calls are one line methods, have you considered using ui-sref (you can pass parameters with these too)? and there must be something else in your code that is changing the state or the url - maybe a redirect? something in a META tag, some default state handler? A module constructor that's changing the state?

Comment: The reason I use `$state` is because I have one service with all views (so i can use `pages.viewName.viewState`, for example: `pages.register.summary(params)`). This is the way my team decided to do state changes so I shouldn't really change it to ui-sref. Can't I do it in my way?

Comment: You can do it any way you like :) I was simply suggesting that if you are writing one line methods, you could reduce the amount of code you need to write, but it sounds like you have a reason, so that's perfectly fine. Really, I'm not upset at all.